# Setting mapping value in constructor has no effect?

Tags: remix, mapping, constructor

In the following smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract MyCoin {
  uint _totalSupply;
  mapping(address => uint) public balances;

  function MyCoin() public {
    _totalSupply = 1;
    balances[msg.sender] = 1;
  }
}
```

If I create the contract as myAddr, and then call `balances(myAddr)`, I should expect to get back `1`, right? However, I get back `0` as the result. What is the explanation?

Maybe worth noting that I'm using remix and the Javascript VM for this, perhaps it's a bug in this particular VM implementation? Still, it seems too basic to be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this, and it worked fine. My guess would be that you failed to enclose your address in quotes when calling `balances()`. I believe Remix interprets an unquoted address as a zero (perhaps because it starts with "0x").

Comment: D'oh, you are right. That's a really unexpected UI failure IMO, and it was made even more confusing because the function returned the proper result for some addresses!